# No visible @interface for 'class' declares the select 'method' when calling super

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

I have the following code,

In `.h` file:

```
@interface MyBaseClass : NSObject
{
    - (void)myMethod;
}
```

In `.m` file:

```
@implementation MyClass2000 : MyBaseClass
{
    - (void) myMethod
    {
        //Does something interesting here
        myData[0] = 0;
        myData[1] = 1;
    }
}
```

Later I created a class that extends "MyClass2000" and is called "MyClass2001"

`.h` file:

```
#import "MyClass2000.h"

@interface MyClass2001 : MyClass2000
@end
```

`.m` file:

```
@implementation MyClass2001 : MyClass2000
{
}
```

This class is exactly the same as "MyClass2000" (but I specifically need to keep them in separate classes, and one extending the other. I also need a "MyClass2002 class", which in this case will need to update only 1 of the indexes, so I tried to call `[super myMethod]` as follows:

The next class extends "MyClass2001"

`.h` file:

```
#import "MyClass2001.h"

@interface MyClass2002 : MyClass2001
@end
```

`.m` file:

```
@implementation MyClass2002 : MyClass2001
{
    - (void) myMethod
    {
        [super myMethod];

        //Only update one value
        myData[1] = 1;
    }
}
```

On that line I'm getting: `No visible @interface for 'MyClass2001' declares the selector 'myMethod'`.

Any tips on how to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: You almost certainly have not appropriately declared your classes and methods in .h files and included them as needed in the .m files.  (You don't show us any of your @interface declarations.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't how you declare a method in Objective-C. In your interface, you declare the method like this:

```
@interface MyClass2000 : MyBaseClass {
    NSString *someVariableDeclaration;
}

- (void) myMethod;

@end
```

And then you implement the function in your .m like this:

```
@implementation MyClass2000 {
    NSString * someDifferentVariableDeclaration;
}
 - (void) myMethod
{
    //Does something interesting here
    myData[0] = 0;  
    myData[1] = 1;
}
@end
```

Comment: Hi! That was an error while entering my sample code. Updated the original post.

Comment: @sandy Why are you wrapping the contents of your implementation in {braces}?

Comment: @sandy You can only make declarations within the braces. See the updated to my answer. Your implementation has to be within `@implementation` and `@end` and not within braces.

Comment: Well, it's working! I'm an Android dev and I hate the feeling of just "winging it" on Objective-C. Wish I had more time to really master it. Thanks!

Comment: Can I also just not have any braces after `@implementation` ?

Answer (score 0):

Where you have the line:

```
[super MyClass2001];
```

Instead you want to have:

```
[super myMethod];
```

You were trying to call a method named `MyClass2001`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

1.Jus check the Inheritance hierarchy. In Objc its necessary to have implementation for every interfaces. But your code tells you don't have MyBaseClass implementation.

2.Method declaration cant be done inside {} in .h.

3.Method definition cant be done inside {} in .m.

4.Implementation does not extended only interface be extended.

It should work if proper hierarchy maintained.